# JavaScript: How to return a modified function with `forEach` or `for` loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, siesta

I've a property name of `items:` which waits for a `array` list.
The normal and running implementation of this code block is below;

```
// This usage works perfectly with `getFirstTest()` function
// And creates a list of Array fine!
harness.start(
    {
        group: 'UI Tests',
        testClass: Siesta.Test.ListClass,
        items: [
            {
              group: 'First Group',
              items: [
                  getFirstTest('Foo'),
                  getFirstTest('Bar'),
                  getFirstTest('Alpha'),
                  getFirstTest('Beta'),
                  getFirstTest('Zet')
              ]
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

but as you'll notice there are lots of iterative statements and therefore I've tried use `forEach` and `for` loops to state `getFirstTest()` function as dynamic but I can not render the `array` list as above, it's not throw any issue but can not create the list!

As well I need to able set several `parameters` on `getFirstTest` function:

e.g.: `getFirstTest('Foo', 'SecondParam')`

```
harness.start(
    {
        group: 'UI Tests',
        testClass: Siesta.Test.ListClass,
        items: [
            {
              group: 'First Group',
              items: this.firstGrpSubmodules
            }
        ]
    }
);

function firstGrpSubmodules () {
    let implementedCases = [
        'Foo', 'Bar', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Zet'
    ];

    // I've tried several ways to achive but couldn't
    // Usage 1: The for loop
    // for (let i=0; i<implementedCases.length; i++) {
    //       let submodules = implementedCases[i];
    //
    //       getFirstTest(submodules);
    // }

    // Usage 2: forEach
    // implementedCases.forEach(function(submodule) {
    //     getFirstTest(submodule);
    // });
}
```

What I'm missing here and how can i achieve for second implementation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters, `firstGrpSubmodules()` isn't returning anything. Either of these methods will work fine if you actually return the new array.

Comment: @ChrisG I've used `return` keyword within `forEach` and `for` loop but doesn't effect anything; still some mistakes exist!

Comment: Basic example using a for loop: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/km5r3Lnt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
harness.start({
  group: 'UI Tests',
  testClass: Siesta.Test.ListClass,
  items: [
    {
      group: 'First Group',
      items: ['Foo', 'Bar'].map(getSalesTest),
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: This is works fine but within `getSalesTest` function I need to set 2 parameters; The `map` gets first parameter but how to state parameter?

Comment: `.map(e => getSalesTest(e, p2, p3))`